# React Testing Library: OnClick isn't working in a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a test like this:

```
it('Side effect should trigger', async ()=>{
   await act(async () => {
      let container = render(<Grandparent/>);
      const btn = container.findByTestId('childBtn');
      fireEvent.click(btn)
   });
   const changedMsg = await container.findByText('Changed');
   expect(changedMsg).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

My components look like this:

Grandparent:

```
const Grandparent = ()=>{
   const [labelText, setLabelText] = useState('Unchanged');
   return (<Parent labelText={labelText} setLabelText={setLabelText}/>);
}
```

Parent:

```
const Parent = ({labelText, setLabelText})=>{
   return (<div>
      <label>{labelText}</label>
      <Child setLabelText={setLabelText} />          
   </div>)
}
```

Child:

```
const Child = ({setLabelText}) =>{
   return(<div>
      <Button data-testid='childBtn' onClick={()=>setLabelText('Changed')}/>
   </div>)
}
```

My issue is that the assertion in my unit test fails. I've logged the return value from `findByTextId('childBtn')` and I am indeed getting a button (something like `<button class='MuiButtonBase-root' data-testid='childBtn'></button>`), but the side effect from clicking it is not going through. I added some logging in the onClick function and it never showed up when I re-ran the test, so the issue is that the onClick handler isn't firing at all.

How do I fix this? Is trying to test something that involves side effects from a bunch of nested components like this not feasible in the first place?

Comment: Have you tried to pass `setLabelText` to Child?, `const Child = () =>{` does not show that :) it should be `const Child = (setLabelText) =>{`

Comment: @AntoineBaqain My bad, that was a typo on my part.. the actual I have code does this

Comment: would simply `btn.click()` be working instead of fireEvent.click(btn)? I'm not asking to change, but wanted to help investigate :)

Comment: @Antoine Baqain A React Component actually receives props and children as params, if you want to use props you need to detructure `const Child = ({setLabelText}) =>{` or do `const Child = (props) =>{ ... props.setLabelText()` ...

Comment: The code was missing props at first, check question edits.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think you have some code mistakes in your unit test since you are mixing react-testing-library API and testing-library, try this:

```
it("Side effect should trigger", async () => {
    const {findByTestId, findByText} = render(<Grandparent />);
    fireEvent.click(await findByTestId("childBtn"));
    const changedMsg = await findByText("Changed");
    expect(changedMsg).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

*I did not test it, but it should work.
act() wrapper is not needed in react-testing-library since the render method is using it internally.*

With react-testing-library you dont' have to care about implementation details of your components, nor you care to test internal state, etc... You just test "What the end user sees on screen in response to certain events". If you need to test functions, like fetch, interactions with global object, etc... you need to mock all those methods.

The philosophy of this approach is to make your unit tests *( which are never funny to write )* so that they won't have to change too often even if you are going to refactor your React Components. You just care about what it' s being rendered as DOM nodes and that's what you have to test.

NOTE: In the code you pasted there are typos btw, props have to be destructured in your code if you want to use them directly without doing props.prop, like : `const Child = ({setLabelText}) =>{` .

Comment: Do I need to mock the internal state too (i.e. labelText/setLabelText)? My assertion is testing for what's in the DOM since it's checking the changed label text, the issue is that the rendered DOM isn't behaving the way I intended because its label doesn't change from clicking the button in <Child/>

Comment: No you don't need to mock the state, I updated the answer, try to fix the unit test code accordingly.